# Error on starting ASP.NET Core React web applicaton on Debian 8.10

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, debian

I created ASP.NET Core React Web Applicaton (VS 2017, Core 2.2, template "React.js and Redux")

Only modification in code was this:

```
public class Program
{
    ...
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
#if !DEBUG
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:80");
#else
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
#endif
    }
```

Then, I published it with following params:

- Publish method "File System";
- Configuration: Release;
- Deployment Mode: Self-Contained;
- Target Runtime: linux-x64

After that, I copied files from folder "publish" to Debian server (Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie))

And then I started it:

```
    root@server:~# dotnet "/var/aspnetcore/publish/WebApplicationReactRedux.dll"
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
          User profile is available. Using '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
    Hosting environment: Production
    Content root path: /root
    Now listening on: http://[::]:80
    Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Up to this point, everything is relatively OK. But when I try to open the site, the following error occurs:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'Page: /Error'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {page = "/Error", action = "", controller = ""}. Executing page /Error
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker[101]
      Executing handler method WebApplicationReactRedux.Pages.ErrorModel.OnGet - ModelState is Valid
```

I tried to do the same thing with a regular .NET Core MVC web-application, and there were no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It cost me some gray hair, but it looks like I figured it out. In some reasons the relative path to ClientApp folder resolves wrong.
In source code below I marked places where I put an absolute path instead of relative one. At least, after that the website began to run correctly.

```
public class Startup
{
   ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            //configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"; <-- this relative path resolves wrong 
            configuration.RootPath = "/var/aspnetcore/publish/ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       ...
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            //spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; <-- this relative path resolves wrong
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "/var/aspnetcore/publish/ClientApp"; 
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

But I still can't explain why the relative path is resolved incorrectly and how to fix it.